# flexbox with multi column layout and mobile div box ordering

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create attached box layout with flexbox.

[image: boxlayout]

My example code is below. 
My challenge is not mobile but desktop view - box item 1 and 2 are not 1 column in this layout. But once I use nesting like below then "order"doesn't work in flexbox. 
parent "flex row" layout -> child "flex column" layout

I suppose "nest" with "mixed row and column flexbox" with "ordering"will not work together.

If someone has any idea to achieve it with flexbox, I want to get help..

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 margin: -10px -10px -10px 180px;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px; 
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 60px; 
  width: 100%;
}
.breadcrumb{
  background: green;
  height: 30px; 
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  flex: 1; 
}

.aside-1 {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
.aside-2 {
  background: gold;
  padding: 10px; 
  flex: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
  .wrapper {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display:flex;
    margin: -10px -10px -10px -10px ;
  }
 
  .main { order: 2; }
  .aside-1 {
    order :1; 
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order :3; }
  .footer { order: 4; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
<header class="header">Header</header>  
  <div class="breadcrumb">Bread</div> 
  <div class="aside-1">Menuline1</div>
  <div class="aside-2"><p>Menucontent</p>
    <p>Menucontent</p>
    <p>Menucontent</p>
    <p>Menucontent</p>
    <p>Menucontent</p>
    <p>Menucontent</p>
    <p>Menucontent</p></div> 
    <div class="main">    
      <p>Contents</p>  
      <p>Contents</p>  
      <p>Contents</p>  
      <p>Contents</p>  
  </div>  
 <footer class="footer">フッター</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654686/does-this-flexbox-based-layout-require-extra-markup?rq=1

Comment: Basically, *unless the height is known*, you need an extra wrapper for the "column" side, which means (until `display:contents` is supported), you **can't** do this with flexbox.

Comment: Hi Paulie, thank you for your comments. As you said I also think if I want to do it by only flexbox , it can't be achieved. I have another solution to achieve this layout, it is box2&3 are in the flexbox, the other elements are usual CSS layout. Then it works. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
 margin: -10px -10px -10px 180px;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px; 
}
.flex{
    display: -webkit-box;/* Android4.3以前ブラウザ用 */
    display: -webkit-flex;/* iOS8以前Safari用 */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin: -10px -20px -10px -10px; 
    flex: 1 100%;
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 60px; 
  width: 100%;
}
.breadcrumb{
  background: green;
  height: 30px; 
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.main {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;/*--- Android4.3以前ブラウザ用 ---*/
     -webkit-flex: 1;/*--- iOS8以前Safari用 ---*/
    flex: 1;
    text-align: left;
    background: deepskyblue;
    flex: 1; 
    margin: -150px 0px 0px 0px; 
}

.aside-1 {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width:320px; 
  height:130px;  
}
.aside-2 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;/*--- Android4.3以前ブラウザ用 ---*/
    -webkit-flex: 1;/*--- iOS8以前Safari用 ---*/
    flex: 1;
    background: gold;
    padding: 10px; 
    max-width:320px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
  .wrapper {
    margin: -10px -10px -10px -10px ;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
  .flex{
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display:flex;
  }
  .header{
    height:10%;
  }
  .breadcrumb{
    height:10%;
  }
  .aside-1
  {
    height: 10%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .main { 
    margin: 0 0 0 0 ;
    order: 1; }
  .aside-2 {
    order :2; 
    min-width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">  
<header class="header">ヘッダー画像</header>  
  <div class="breadcrumb">パンくずリスト</div> 
  <div class="aside-1">メニュー文言</div>
    <div class="flex">
  <div class="aside-2"><p>メニュー内容</p>
    <p>メニュー内容</p>
    <p>メニュー内容</p>
    <p>メニュー内容</p>
    <p>メニュー内容</p>
    <p>メニュー内容</p>
    <p>メニュー内容</p></div> 
    <div class="main">    
      <p>メインコンテンツがここに入ります</p>  
      <p>メインコンテンツがここに入ります</p>  
      <p>メインコンテンツがここに入ります</p>  
      <p>メインコンテンツがここに入ります</p>  
  </div>  
      </div>
 <footer class="footer">フッター</footer>
</div>
```

As @yaycmyk said, box 3 needs absolute layout and to use flexbox only 2 and 3. It is not better solution but it can be one of solution... thank you guys and ladies.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to absolutely position box 3 conditionally to achieve this layout.

Comment: Thank you yaycmyk, I have another solution and I will put it into below.